# postgres function insert and update

Tags: postgresql

I have a function:

```
create function fn_name_here() returns int as
$$
begin
    with c as (
    Select a1.accounts_id,sum(a2.quantity * a2.unit_price) as MRR
    from account_subscriptions a1 
    inner join order_item a2 on a1.subscription_id = a2.account_subscriptions_id 
    group by a1.accounts_id
    )
    update summary s set MRR = c.MRR 
    from c
    where c.accounts_id = s.accounts_id;
return 0;
end;
$$ language plpgsql
```

With the query I get `accounts_id` and `mrr` and update `mrr` in the `summary` table by comparing `accounts_id`.

But I also need a new row with `accounts_id` and `mrr` to be inserted in the `summary` table if `accounts_id` is not already present there, but it is throwing an error.

when i am editing it with this query and calling the function

```
UPDATE dummy s SET mrr = c.MRR from c WHERE c.accounts_id = s.accounts_id ;    
IF NOT FOUND THEN
   INSERT INTO dummy (mrr,accounts_id)
      select c.mrr,c.accounts_id from c;
END IF;
```

it is throwing the error

```
relation "c" does not exist
LINE 1: ...TO dummy (mrr,accounts_id) select c.mrr,c.accounts_id from c
```

Comment: Why the [tag:mysql] tag?

Comment: please update post with error you get

Comment: which version of postgres  you are using ?

Answer (score 0):

The table `c` only exists in the scope of the `UPDATE` statement, and you cannot reference it from a later SQL statement in the same function.

Unstead of using `UPDATE`, you should use `INSERT ... ON CONFLICT ... UPDATE`, which does exactly what you need. All you need is a primary key or unique constraint on `summary(accounts_id)`.

Comment: This feature is available from version of postgres 9.5 and greater. @naina if you are using 9.5 or greater then this will be best solution.

Answer (score 0):

**Note: this is tested on 9.4.**

**In 9.5 or greater new functionality has been introduced for insert.**

Follow below step to check insert or update. You can refer this and update your function accordingly.

Step 1:

```
CREATE TABLE public.test
(
  col1 text,
  col2 text,
  col3 integer
);
```

Step 2:

```
insert into test values ('Old', 'Old', 1);
```

Step 3:

```
drop function if exists test_insert_update();

create function test_insert_update() returns int as
$$
Declare findId boolean;
begin
    /* Main Query starts from here as you have asked to create function that is why it is wrapped into it. This is sample example you can 
       modify it as per your requirement. */

    with updateInsert as (
    Select '' as col1,'updated' as col2, col3
    from test abc   
    where col3 = 1
    union  
    Select 'notUpdated' as col1, 'notUpdated' as col2, 2 as col3

    ), updateValues as (
        -- this only updates your results  
    update test c1 set col3 = updateInsert.col3
        , col2 = updateInsert.col2
    from updateInsert
    where updateInsert.col3 = c1.col3
    RETURNING *     
    /* 
       I tried the example using with RETURNING * and without RETURNING *  and both the time I recieved expected 
       result but in PostgreSQL documentation it is written in with clause. 
       As per documentation : 9.4 
        INSERT conforms to the SQL standard, except that the RETURNING clause is a PostgreSQL extension, 
        as is the ability to use WITH with INSERT. Also, the case in which a column name list is omitted, 
        but not all the columns are filled from the VALUES clause or query, is disallowed by the standard.
    */
    ) 
   Insert into test (col1, col2, col3) 
    select * from updateInsert where not exists(select * from test c1 where c1.col3 = updateInsert.col3);  
    /* Not exists clause is written to remove rows which has been updated. */

    /* END */    
return 0;
end;
$$ 
language 'plpgsql';
```

Step 5:

```
select * from test_insert_update();
```

Step 6:

```
select * from test;
```

Comment: This code is subject to a race condition. If e.g. a row is inserted by a concurrent transaction that commits *after* the `SELECT` in your first CTE (BTW, why is `col3 = 1` and `col3 = 2` hard coded?), but *before* the `INSERT`, your function will fail. You have to write an endless loop for `UPSERT`, retrying until either `INSERT` or `UPDATE` succeeds.

Comment: Those are dummy queries just to test insert and update.  I added one union to test insert function. As I know col3 = 1 is already present in table so it should be updated and col3 = 3 should be inserted.